# MySQL Putting in duplicate id's

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run an UPDATE query that uses the same table and I'm getting an error saying "1093 - Table 'queues_monitor_times' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data".

```
UPDATE queues_monitor_times 
SET queue_id = IF((
        SELECT id
        FROM queues_monitor_times
        INNER JOIN(
        SELECT pcc_group, pcc, gds, queue, category, `name`
        FROM queues_monitor_times
        GROUP BY pcc_group, pcc, gds, queue, category, `name`
        HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
        )temp ON queues_monitor_times.pcc_group = temp.pcc_group AND 
                queues_monitor_times.pcc = temp.pcc AND 
                queues_monitor_times.gds = temp.gds AND 
                queues_monitor_times.queue = temp.queue AND 
                queues_monitor_times.category = temp.category AND 
                queues_monitor_times.`name` = temp.`name`), 1, id)
WHERE
    id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM queues_old GROUP BY pcc_group, pcc, gds, queue, category, `name`);
```

I ran the select query by itself and it showed all the rows that were duplicates, which is what I wanted. I want queue_id to be set with the lowest duplicate row's id if the row is a duplicate or the row id if it is not.

Example of what the query should do:

```
id  dup_id   name      value
1   1        John      13
2   2        John      13
3   3        Sally     6
4   4        Frank     4
5   5        Sally     6
```

And after running the query it will turn into

```
id  dup_id   name      value
1   1        John      13
2   1        John      13
3   3        Sally     6
4   4        Frank     4
5   3        Sally     6
```

Please advise and thank you for your help.

Comment: The documentation page of the [`UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) explains: *"You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."*

Comment: wrap it in a other subquery that should work.. `IF(( SELECT id FROM ( SELECT id FROM queues_monitor_times ... )`

Comment: @johnreeves I only quoted from the documentation. If the documentation is not correct then complain at MySQL (aka Oracle). But if you look closely to your queries you'll notice that it tells the truth.

Comment: @axiac - I ran this `UPDATE queues_monitor_times SET queue_id = (SELECT id FROM queues WHERE queues.pcc_group = queues_monitor_times.pcc_group AND queues.pcc = queues_monitor_times.pcc AND queues.gds = queues_monitor_times.gds AND queues.queue = queues_monitor_times.queue 
AND queues.category = queues_monitor_times.category
 AND queues.name = queues_monitor_times.name) 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM queues_old GROUP BY pcc_group, pcc, gds, queue, category, name);` and it worked. What's the difference?

Comment: It does not select from `queues_monitor_times`.

Comment: @axiac - Oh I see

Comment: I suspect the reason for this limitation is the two kinds of (probably incompatible) locks that `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements put on the table during the query.

Comment: How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. Thanks for all your help!

```
UPDATE queues_monitor_times 
    SET queue_id = (
    SELECT
        id 
    FROM
        queues_old 
    WHERE
        queues_old.pcc_group = queues_monitor_times.pcc_group 
        AND queues_old.pcc = queues_monitor_times.pcc 
        AND queues_old.gds = queues_monitor_times.gds 
        AND queues_old.queue = queues_monitor_times.queue 
        AND queues_old.category = queues_monitor_times.category
        AND queues_old.`name` = queues_monitor_times.`name` 
    GROUP BY pcc_group, pcc, gds, queue, category, `name`
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) 
WHERE
    id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM queues_old GROUP BY pcc_group, pcc, gds, queue, category, `name`);
```

***For those that will want to use this in the future, queues_monitor_times table and queues_old table have the exact same data.***